# OpenUI5 - Custom configuration property

Tags: sapui5

Is there a way to have a custom OpenUI5/SAPUI5 configuration property?

For example, if I wanted to add a property "xx-customProperty".

It would be nice to hook into the existing configuration support (url param loading for example).

I took a look at sap.ui.core.Configuration, and I see where the M_SETTINGS map is defined, but not how to append to it.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration properties are related with framework settings. if you want to check in your application whether xx-customProperty is set as URI parameter then you can use

```
jQuery.sap.getUriParameters().get("xx-customProperty")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good way to get a url param value. But this doesn't seem to help hooking my custom property into the framework's configuration support (for example being able to set the property with window["sap-ui-config"])